# how to change view size at Runtime

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

If orientation changes at runtime I want to show to fragments side to side. What I did is declare two framelayouts with the second size zero in terms of height and width.

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/conversation_history"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"/>


    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and then when orientation changed I tried resizing the frame layouts. Instead of each fragment occupying half of the screen both overlap and occupy the whole screen. So why do both occupy the whole screen instead of occupying half of the screen?

```java
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
                int portraitWidth,portriatHeight;
                portraitWidth = frame.getWidth();
                portriatHeight = frame.getHeight();
                frame.getLayoutParams().width = portriatHeight/2;
                frame.getLayoutParams().height = portraitWidth/2;
                frame.setX(0);
                frame.setY(0);
                frame.requestLayout();
                frame.invalidate();

                FrameLayout contentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.conversation_history);
                contentFrame.getLayoutParams().width = portriatHeight/2;
                contentFrame.getLayoutParams().height = portraitWidth/2;
                contentFrame.setX(portriatHeight/2);
                contentFrame.setY(portraitWidth/2);
                contentFrame.requestLayout();
                contentFrame.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a determinant number of Fragments displaying on the screen, seems like you do/will.

I would highly recommend just creating a Layout Landscape Variation. The system will notice an orientation change has occurred and look for a related layout - located right below your res -> layout-land folder.

If you don't have one and are using Android Studio, simply open your layout in Design mode and locate the file icon with the Android head by it, click on that - and select "create landscape layout"

Comment: I know this is the easiest approach but not always do I neeed to show to 2 adjacent tabs In landscape. it depends on which fragment is showing. some don't require to have 2 fragments showing side by side in landscape

Comment: It looks like they are the same width and height. Have you considered using something like a horizontal linear layout with a frame layout for each fragment, adjust their width to wrap content and assign them both a weight of 1. Then if you have no secondary fragment to display then just grab a reference to your right most frame and set the visibility to gone.